# Best options to host an ethereum react dapp to a custom domain

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, dapp-design, server-side

I'm looking for best options to host an ethereum dapp created using react and drizzle, with the following requirements:

1. It needs to be hosted in a custom domain (.com / .net /  OR .io ) that I have purchased.
2. It contains both client side scripts (static pages) and server side scripts (which individually interact with the smart contract in the blockchain).
3. It should have good scalability and accessibility by users.
4. I have an old hosting space that i purchased long back in DreamHost and HostGator. is it possible to use that for dapp hosting? What web servers would i need to install in it (apache? php?) ?

I have heard about heroku, digitalOcean, google and aws... any specifics would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vercel](https://vercel.com/) is an option which would meet your requirements:

1. You can link your own domain to a Vercel deployed site.
2. Both client and server side can be accomplished.  Server side involves a [serverless function](https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/introduction), which isn't too difficult (especially now they've clarified their [CORS advice](https://vercel.com/knowledge/how-to-enable-cors)).  I tend to push to Vercel through linking it to github, but you can do it via other means (e.g. CLI).
3. Vercel serves 4.5B requests a week.  Not sighted on your use case, but it can probably accommodate you?
4. Not sure about these providers, but I've hosted a DApp on my home server using Apache, Node and React; so if they allow you to use those technologies, sure - there are other ways of doing it too though.  It is a potch to set up though - Vercel is easier.

Of course whether it is the 'best' is rather subjective, I haven't tried that many other options, but I like it.

Answer (score 0):

you could just bundle everything with webpack and host it on github pages. thats free and you will be able to use your custom domain

Comment: but does it allow server-side scripts using node.js & express ? i thought it was more for storing static client side pages.

Comment: you're right gh pages isn't for you then, you should probably try heroku.

Answer (score 0):

`Vercel` is a dedicated platform for static site deployment and serverless functions. It also comes with a Github action for continuous deployment. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/vercel-action

```
1. Sign up for a Vercel account at https://vercel.com/signup.
2. Install the Vercel CLI globally by running npm install -g vercel in your terminal.
3. Navigate to your dapp's project directory.
4. Build your React app by running npm run build or yarn build.
5. Once the build is complete, run vercel in your terminal.
6. Follow the CLI prompts to configure your project settings, including specifying your custom domain.
7. Vercel will provide you with a deployment URL for your dApp.
```

Another option you can consider is `Fleek`. Fleek is a platform specifically designed for hosting decentralized applications (dapps) on IPFS (InterPlanetary File System) and Ethereum.
https://fleek.co/hosting/

Regarding your existing hosting space with DreamHost and HostGator, it might be possible to use them for dapp hosting, but it depends on the specific hosting plans and configurations they offer.

Vercel, allows you to add a namespace to your domain registry which might be useful in your case. You can read more here https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/domains